# Pascal's triangle - Copying between 2 arrays

Tags: c++

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    const int nmax = 15;
    int zeile[nmax];
    int zeiletmp[nmax];

    for(int n = 0; n < nmax; ++n) {
        for(int k = 0; k < n; ++k) zeiletmp[k] = zeile[k];

        zeile[0] = 1;
        zeile[n] = 1;

        for(int k = 1; k < n; ++k) zeile[k] = zeiletmp[k] + zeiletmp[k - 1];

        cout << setw(6 * (nmax - n) / 2) << zeile[0];
        for(int k = 1; k <= n; k++) cout << setw(6) << zeile[k];
        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I want to know when we copy the elements of the array zeile into zeiletemp, my question is what exactly is being copied? We just defined the dimensions of both structures, but nothing regarding the elements that they contain. So what is being copied ?

Comment: "*I want to know when we copy the elements of the arrow `zeile` into `zeiletemp`, my question is what exactly is being copied?*" `n` elements inside `zeile` is being copied to `zeiletmp`? (Note that the value of `n` changes with each iteration in the outer `for`-loop.) All elements inside an array are "defined" as soon as you declare it.

Comment: If you are talking about this line: ```for(int k = 0; k < n; ++k) zeiletmp[k] = zeile[k];``` on the first iteration nothing is copied because n = 0, also nothing is in the array yet. Follow the code then see what is being copied after each iteration and see what numbers are being put into each array

Comment: @Ruks and what elements do they contain, when I simply declare the arrays but do not specify what elements they contain ?

Comment: They contain all `1`'s apparently, because it's set here `zeile[n] = 1;`.

Comment: @rustyx zeile[n]=1 means that the last element of it as well as the first one are both evaluated as 1's or no?

Comment: @rustyx and most importantly the copying happens before the "zeile[n] = 1;" part

Comment: @imbAF the copying up to `n` happens before, by that time all values less than `n` are set in previous iterations of the loop.

Comment: Yes I know. but the thing is this is the exercise that was required for us to do, with only 3 lecturers on C++ with no prior background to programming. And it's lazy writing.Up until now we used the"{" for loops and now suddenly there are no "{" anymore. So I don't know where a loop starts and where it ends and what it includes in its block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is ambiguous, but if you want to know where you added the elements in the other array, the following two lines are Your answer.

```
zeiletmp[k] = zeile[k];
zeile[k] = zeiletmp[k] + zeiletmp[k - 1];
```